# With opencv,How to use not erosion/dilation but connectedComponentsWithStas to remove dots?

Tags: point, opencv3.0, noise

I have read this:

[Remove spurious small islands of noise in an image - Python OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369031/remove-spurious-small-islands-of-noise-in-an-image-python-opencv)

erosion/dilation are suggested,and just wondering is it possible to do same thing by using connectedComponectsStats?I have googled,got these:

http://www.itkeyword.com/doc/5188188731707068417/how-to-use-opencvs-connected-components-with-stats-in-python

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html#corner-with-subpixel-accuracy

but from these,I can't figure out how to remove dots,so would you please tell me how to do it,thanks in advance!

update:
What I really want to do is extracting human shape from blow image by remove small dots.

[image: demo image]

Comment: Using stats, you could use the flag `cv2.CC_STAT_AREA` to remove dots with respect to their area. Additionally, if you know the location of the dots to remove you could use the `centroid`. I don't quite get what you don't understand.

Comment: @RickM.,thanks,I think a area is produced by a ploygon(should be very small),I don't know how to remove this small polygon.With controid and boudaries in hand,I can only remove a rectangle,am I right or I missunderstand something?

Comment: The area corresponds to the area of the contour. This doesn't necessarily have to be a contour. What exactly do you mean by dots? Can you upload an image?

Comment: @RickM.,I added an image,and what I really want to do is extract human shape from image.

Comment: I've added an answer, accept it or comment if it helps you or not!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `connectedComponentsWithStats` you can do something like this:

```
img = cv2.imread(directory + "canny.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
labelnum, labelimg, contours, GoCs = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(gray)
for label in xrange(1, labelnum):
    x,y,w,h,size = contours[label]
    if size <= 50:
         img[y:y+h, x:x+w] = 0
cv2.imwrite(directory + "cca_image.png", img)
```

For the image you uploaded, I got this as the result :

[image: Result image]

Does this work for you? I guess dilation/erosion before calling `connectedComponentsWithStats` would help, but I leave that for you to decide.