# OpenCV python code to calculate distance of object relative to a point

Tags: python, opencv

Consider the image below:

[image]

I want to write an OpenCV program to calculate the distance (blue line) in pixels between the midpoint of the table (red dot) and the midpoint of the brown box (blue dot).

I figured using I would use `cv2.findContours` to find the boundaries of the table, the boundaries of the box, get the midpoint of the table, the midpoint of the box and then probably use `dist.euclidean` to calculate the distance between the box's midpoint and table's midpoint. **However, I am stuck at this point:**

[image]

My code (shown below) is drawing contours for the wires and the glare and I have no interest in them:

```
cv2.namedWindow("Object detector", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)    
image = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE)

cv2.resizeWindow('Object detector', 800, 600)

im_bw = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,2))
morphology_img = cv2.morphologyEx(im_bw, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel,iterations=1)

edged = cv2.Canny(morphology_img, 50, 100)
edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=1)

cnts= cv2.findContours(edged.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts)

cv2.drawContours(image, cnts, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

orig = image.copy()

cv2.imshow('Object detector', image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I even added the following piece of code to filter out contours of a certain size:

```
for (i, c) in enumerate(cnts):
    # if the contour is not sufficiently large, ignore it
    if cv2.contourArea(c) < 50000:
        continue
    else:        
        box = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
        box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)
        box = np.array(box, dtype="int")
        cv2.drawContours(image, [box.astype("int")], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        (tl, tr, br, bl) = box
        (tltrX, tltrY) = midpoint(tl, tr)
        (blbrX, blbrY) = midpoint(bl, br)
        (tlblX, tlblY) = midpoint(tl, bl)
        (trbrX, trbrY) = midpoint(tr, br)        
        # compute the Euclidean distance between the midpoints
        dA = dist.euclidean((tltrX, tltrY), (blbrX, blbrY))
        dB = dist.euclidean((tlblX, tlblY), (trbrX, trbrY))
        cv2.putText(image, "{:.1f}".format(dA),
        (int(tltrX - 15), int(tltrY - 10)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.65, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(image, "{:.1f}".format(dB),
        (int(trbrX + 10), int(trbrY)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.65, (255, 255, 255), 2)
```

But even that didn't help.

[image]

How can I accomplish this task of calculating relative distance of the box from the center of the table?

Comment: Is your question how to detect the point or to measure a distance, once you have the points?

Comment: @Micka Thank you for the response. My goal is to measure the distance once I have the points but right now, I can't even get the points with my current strategy.

Comment: Measuring the straight distance (in pixel) between pointA and pointB is just dist = cv2.norm(pointA - pointB). Detection isnt simple. If you have one single task like a scientific dataset, I recommend to annotate the points manuall, for example with labelImg. If you have to do it in many datasets try to add detectable markers to your objects.

Comment: @Micka I have two markers on the table whose contours in the image above got generated properly. Would it be a good idea to measure the distance between one of those markers and the box? The box's contour does not look usable.

Comment: You should place a detectable markeron the box, if possible

Comment: additional context: https://forum.opencv.org/t/find-distance-of-object-along-a-line/9525

Comment: @Micka _You should place a detectable markeron the box, if possible –_ How will that help me?

Comment: @a_sid with detectable marker you solve the detection part of your problem.

Comment: @Micka Ok. How do I filter out all the other contours that I don't want from the image (stray wires, glare, etc.)?

Comment: By detecting the marker you detect the marker and not contours. For example QR Code detection would be such kind of marker detection.

Comment: @Micka _By detecting the marker you detect the marker and not contours._ Does this mean I'll have to shift my focus away from `cv2.findContours`?

Comment: I agree with @Micka. It is easier if you have some recognizable marker on the table to detect instead. Finding the midpoint of this table and box is a lot harder, especially when the table and box are featureless. You will have an easier job ignoring any outliers by shifting focus to detect the marker instead. OpenCV has methods for generating and detecting arUco markers, for example that are pretty robust. Your proposal with `cv2.findContours` requires much effort for a limited use case. Generating two patterns, printing them out and putting them in the environment will make your life easier.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you for the prompt response. _ Generating two patterns, printing them out and putting them in the environment will make your life easier._ Oh are you referring to the arUco markers? Are you saying I should print out the markers and place them on the table?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.